# Talend - Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: timeout, etl, talend

I use the ETL Talend Open Studio (TOS). I want transfered a data base A into a data base B. I use a tMap component. When I use a tLogRow to look results, it's ok. TOS shows data correctly. But when I make the transfer, TOS writes **"Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"**.

I don't understand this problem... It's ok for the reading of data but there is a problem for the writing of data. 
Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base A contains  300 articles. I think that this problem is caused by Talend Open Studio. TOS can't execute more 100 articles. I have tried to "cut" the base A in three bases. Then, I run TOS. The error has missing. It's strange... but it works.

Answer (score 4):

Try running your job using a single connection to Mysql ( I assume you are using it as the error is a mysql error )

The error above can occur when you attempt to insert/update/delete from two or more connections concurrently.

to create a single connection and have all components share it you will need a pair of components: "tMysqlConnection" and "tMysqlCommit"

the Connection component should be placed before you attempt to query the database. Once you have it in the job, you can link the tMysqlInput components to it by selecting "use existing connection"

The Commit component will issue the commit command and close the transaction.

You will need Connection components for each separate DB server you are working with.